# Switch Statement not reading the variable

Tags: c

My first if statement is working but the after the switch statement is not working. When I enter integer it immediately displays the switch defoult. This is written in C.

```
int choice, mark3;
float mark1, mark2;
float total;
char status[50];

printf("\nEnter type of assesment  :");
scanf("%d", &choice);

if(choice==1)
{
    printf("\nEnter Quiz 1 and Quiz 2 marks  : ");
    scanf("%f, %f", &mark1, &mark2);
    
    printf("\nAssesment Type  :%d", choice);
    printf("\nQuiz Total  :%f", mark1+mark2);
}

else if(choice==2)
{
    printf("\ Enter assignment mark   :");
    scanf("%d", &mark3);
    
    switch(mark3)
    {
        case '1' :
            printf("\nRe-do Assignmnet");
            break;
        case '70' :
            printf("\nGood");
            break;
        case'100' :
            printf("\nEcellent");
            break;
        
        default:
        printf("\nInvalid assessment code entered");
        
    }
return 0;
    
}
```

This is my code.

Comment: `case '1'` should be `case 1`. That is, it needs to be an integer literal not a character literal. Same for the other cases.

Comment: Note that only 3 scores will be given a printed qualifier message — `1`, `70` and `100` (once you remove the single quotes around those numbers in the `case` labels).  All other values are deemed invalid.  If you want ranges, use `if` statements and not a `switch` statement.  The comma in the 'choice 1' input format means you have to type a comma in the input.  You should be checking that the `scanf()` statements return the correct value (2 for the entry of two marks; 1 otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

Here you should try `case 1:` instead of `case '1':`
In similar fashion you should write `case 70:` and `case 100:`
Your compiler is interpreting '1' '70' and '100' as a character due to
`' '` (symbol)

Answer (score 1):

`mark3` is an `int`. But in your `switch-case` you are treating it as `char`. '1' means character 1 rather than integer 1.

Correct your code as follows:

```c
    switch(mark3)
    {
        case 1 :
            printf("\nRe-do Assignmnet");
            break;
        case 70 :
            printf("\nGood");
            break;
        case 100 :
            printf("\nEcellent");
            break;
        
        default:
        printf("\nInvalid assessment code entered");
        break;
        
    }
```